# jQuery validate with multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Theres a lot of people asking a similar question, but all the answers are for a single error message, which is built into the API.

```
.validate({
    groups: {
        birthday: "month day year"
    },
```

Please check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/atLV4/36/

If you submit without running anything, all elements get the error class. As you fill out the form, you can update only one element, deselect it and the error message will disappear even though the other elements haven't been updated. Also, the border is disappearing as soon as you update the select, which causes jumping. I want the validation to only run once all 3 inputs have been selected.

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` ?

Comment: we would like to see some code...

Comment: Good question! Could you post a code snippet or a JSFiddle?

Comment: Is requirement that each `select` have a `value` to validate form ? If all three selects do not have value, call single error function ?

Comment: I just write a simple custom rule - http://jsfiddle.net/atLV4/40/#update. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that jQuery Validate doesn't have a built-in `onchange` function, which is where you'd want to put this for your 3 selects.  Instead, you'll want to disable `onfocusout` and `onclick` checking, then add an external `change` event for the 3 selects, which triggers the validation once all 3 are filled.  For your validate code, you need this:

```
   //save the validate object to use later!
    var $validate = $("#commentForm").validate({
        onfocusout: false,
        onclick: false,
        groups: {
            birthday: "month day year"
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var name = element.prop("name");
            if (name === "month" || name === "day" || name === "year") {
                error.insertAfter("select[name='year']");
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
```

And then you will also need a change event handler:

```
//I'm using generic selectors here, but you may need to specify the 3 of interest
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($('select:filled').length == 3) {
        $('select').each(function () {
            $validate.element(this);
        });
    }
});
```

[$validate.element()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/) is the function which actually checks that they are passing the rules, and updates their borders and error messages appropriately.  Checking for `$('select:filled')` is just short-hand for confirming that all 3 selects have a value.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/atLV4/41/